# Options Page Not Loading from .json in WordPress?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have ACF Pro bundled into my Custom WP Theme and followed the instructions here: [Including ACF within a plugin or theme](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-within-a-plugin-or-theme/) I set up a acf-json folder and resaved all my field groups and they all saved themselves into a .json files (6 total) as expected including my Options page included as well.

So I pushed this out to my staging/dev website to test - all the field groups loaded except for the Options page for some strange reason? I now have the ability to sync up 5 field groups to the dev site but it should show (6) 1 for each of the .json files in my /acf-json/ folder. (My options page settings is at /acf-json/group_60de1e5c.....json)

Is there any know issues I should be aware of or am I missing something here? Here is my code if someone can examine it for me: https://www.codepile.net/pile/Y0An7v1b

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was also pulling in the options page via a php page and that's why it wouldn't load in the .json file.